# "Is deceased" checkbox and Views

Tags: drupal, profile, drupal-views

We have a simple directory built with Views and a few exposed filters for searching. One of the (non-exposed) filters is intended to make sure all listed contacts are not marked as deceased. However, the filter does not have a negate option so instead of `Is Deceased NOT TRUE` we have to do `Is Deceased FALSE`. We may have even had to set the 'Is Deceased' field to 0 in the database directly, I can't recall. That part was working fine.

[image: 'Is deceased' filter in views]

However, we also have a simple profile set up to allow editing of the contacts, adding a photo, and marking as deceased as necessary. What we've found is that when a contact is edited (to update the address or add a photo for example), the "Is Deceased" field is reset to NULL and this excludes them from the directory (because the field does not equal FALSE anymore).

What is a better way to handle this?

Comment: This seems like a general problem with views integration - civicrm boolean yes/no fields often need a more complex selection than True or False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I removed the "Is Deceased" option from the profile we use to edit the contact's information and created a separate profile which contains only that field. It's a little clunky to present two edit links:

- Edit contact information
- Mark contact as deceased

...but it works for now. I would have tried it in a Webform (with [Webform CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm)) but I don't think the image handling pushes back into CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

Since the end goal is to display data in Views, can you use a small module to alter the views query, rather than customizing Civi? I haven't tried views_query_substitutions personally (I've usually hooked into views_query_alter), but I think this is a simple fix that could solve the problem:

```
function hook_views_query_substitutions($view) {
  // Example from views_views_query_substitutions().

  return array(
    "civicrm_contact.is_deceased = '0'" => "civicrm_contact.is_deceased = '0' OR civicrm_contact.is_deceased IS NULL",
  );
}
```

Comment: I gave it a quick try and it didn't take but I appreciate the idea. I will keep this in my back pocket for the future but can't devote too much time to this minor issue.